# How do I use Selenium in Python to find the correct "layout" for amazon search page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Python 3.5 to scrape some product information off of amazon.com. During the process of automating the "search-grabinfo" process, I found out that it breaks when the layout of the page changes. Currently I know of 2 different layouts and I want to have an if condition of the form:

```
if layout = DefaultLayout:
    #do something...
elif layout = ListLayout:
    #do something differently...
else:
    pass
```

I was able to find the `<div class>` tag for this layout option but I'm not able to grab it using selenium to use in my `if` condition

For the Default Layout: `<div id="searchTemplate" class="searchTemplate defaultLayout so_us_en" >...</div>`
For the List Layout: `<div id="searchTemplate" class="searchTemplate listLayout so_us_en" >...</div>`

Using XPath does not seem to be an option since it is of the form `"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1350]/td[2]/span/span[4]"`with tr[i] not being constant

Comment: Any XPath starting with `/html` is almost guaranteed to be brittle and often fail. You should invest some time in learning proper XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I right understood the question you can use this template:

```
# check if defaultLayout is on the page
defaultLayout = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'searchTemplate' and @class = 'searchTemplate defaultLayout so_us_en']")

# check if listLayout is on the page
listLayout = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'searchTemplate' and @class = 'searchTemplate listLayout so_us_en']")

if not defaultLayout:
    #do something...
elif not listLayout:
    #do something differently...
else:
    pass
```

The idea of this template is to get a list of elements and check if the list is empty or not.

***Note:*** I have used `find_elements` because it returns a list of elements found and if there were no elements found, it won't throw any exception, just return an empty list.